# Mockk matching and overloaded function withArg

Tags: kotlin, mockk, mockk-verify

Hello I am trying to find a way to match an overloaded function inside of the verify using `withArg`

The doc doesnt really point this out

```
    every { getResponse.Ids } returns listOf(121212L)
    assert( client.getExtIds(Ids) )
    verify {
        client.getExtIdsCall().call(
            withArg {
                assertEquals(GetExtIdsRequest.builder()
                    .withIds("foo")
                    .withType("bar")
                    .build().hashCode(), it.hashCode()
                )
            }
        )
    }
```

Something like above. But unfortunately I cant because the `client.getExtIdsCall().call()` accepts two different types of objects. One of which has the `hashCode` I want. So the `it` can not be referred correctly to call the hashCode function

Comment: One alternative I found is to overwrite the `equals` method of the object class and just use verify with `eq` instead of `withArg`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can resolve this by explicitly specifying the type parameter of function `withArg`, e.g. if you want your parameter to be a `Long`, you can write:

```
withArg<Long> { ... }
```

Comment: Didnt realize this was an option. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/796) in the Mocck github page, seems like the recommended approach is to use `match` instead of `withArgs` to make this verification.